# MongoDB - Pipeline $lookup with $group losing fields

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I only have 2 years exp with SQL databases and 0 with NoSQL database. I am trying to write a pipeline using MongoDB Compass aggregate pipeline tool that performs a lookup, group, sum, and sort. I am using MongoDB compass to try and accomplish this. Also, please share any resources that make learning this easier, I've not had much like finding good and easy-to-understand examples online with using the compass to accomplish these tasks. Thank you.

An example question I am trying to solve is:

What customer placed the highest number of orders?

Example Data is:

Customer Collection:

```
[
  { "_id": { "$oid": "6276ba2dd1dfd6f5bf4b4f53" },  
    "Id": "1",  
    "FirstName": "Maria",  
    "LastName": "Anders",  
    "City": "Berlin",  
    "Country": "Germany",  
    "Phone": "030-0074321"}, 
  { "_id": { "$oid": "6276ba2dd1dfd6f5bf4b4f54" },  
    "Id": "2",  
    "FirstName": "Ana",  
    "LastName": "Trujillo",  
    "City": "México D.F.",  
    "Country": "Mexico",  
    "Phone": "(5) 555-4729" }
]
```

Order Collection:

```
[
  { "_id": { "$oid": "6276ba9dd1dfd6f5bf4b501f" },  
    "Id": "1",  
    "OrderDate": "2012-07-04 00:00:00.000",  
    "OrderNumber": "542378",  
    "CustomerId": "85",  
    "TotalAmount": "440.00" },
  { "_id": { "$oid": "6276ba9dd1dfd6f5bf4b5020" },  
    "Id": "2",  
    "OrderDate": "2012-07-05 00:00:00.000",  
    "OrderNumber": "542379",  
    "CustomerId": "79",  
    "TotalAmount": "1863.40" }
]
```

I have spent all day looking at YouTube videos and MongoDB documentation but I am failing to comprehend a few things. One, at the time I do a `$group` function I lose all the fields not associated with the group and I would like to keep a few fields. I would like to have it returned the name of the customer with the highest order.

The pipeline I was using that gets me part of the way is the following:

```
[{
   $lookup: {
      from: 'Customer',
      localField: 'CustomerId',
      foreignField: 'Id',
      as: 'CustomerInfo'
 }}, {
   $project: {
      CustomerId: 1,
      CustomerInfo: 1
 }}, {
   $group: {
      _id: '$CustomerInfo.Id',
      CustomerOrderNumber: {
   $sum: 1
  }
 }}, {
   $sort: {
      CustomerOrderNumber: -1
 }}]
```

Example data this returns in order:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Apologies for the bad formatting, still trying to get the hang of posting questions that are easy to understand and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$group` stage, it only returns documents with `_id` and `CustomerOrderNumber` fields, so `CustomerInfo` field was missing.

1. `$lookup`
2. `$project` - From 1st stage, `CustomerInfo` returns as an array, hence getting the first document as a document field instead of an array field.
3. `$group` - Group by `CustomerId`, sum the documents as `CustomerOrderNumber`, and take the first document as `CustomerInfo`.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.
5. `$setWindowsFields` - With [$denseRank](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/denseRank/) to rank the document position by `CustomerOrderNumber` (DESC). If there are documents with same `CustomerOrderNumber`, the [ranking will treat them as same rank/position](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/denseRank/#behavior).
6. `$match` - Select documents with `denseRankHighestOrder` is 1 (highest).

```
db.Order.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Customer",
      localField: "CustomerId",
      foreignField: "Id",
      as: "CustomerInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      CustomerId: 1,
      CustomerInfo: {
        $first: "$CustomerInfo"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$CustomerInfo.Id",
      CustomerOrderNumber: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      CustomerInfo: {
        $first: "$CustomerInfo"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      CustomerId: "$_id",
      CustomerOrderNumber: 1,
      CustomerName: {
        $concat: [
          "$CustomerInfo.FirstName",
          " ",
          "$CustomerInfo.LastName"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        CustomerOrderNumber: -1
      },
      output: {
        denseRankHighestOrder: {
          $denseRank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      denseRankHighestOrder: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bQjrOGqznUY)

---

**Note:**

`$sort` stage able to sort the document by `CustomerOrderNumber`. But if you try to limit the documents such as "SELECT TOP n", the output result may be incorrect when there are multiple documents with the same CustomerOrderNumber/rank.

Example: SELECT TOP 1 Customer who has the highest CustomerOrderNumber but there are 3 customers who have the highest CustomerOrderNumber.